# c# Devexpress dynamic grouping

Tags: c#, devexpress, report, grouping

I have a question about Devexpress report grouping.I have a report and I want to do that tgrouping count make differrent.Thank you for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

Header Grouping is there in that you can select [image]

in this image there is group fields in that u can select the appropriate group field Name to group